# Unable to update the service label for the load balancer forwarding rule

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have created a load balancer forwarding rule without a service label.

Now I am trying to add a service label to the load balancer forwarding rule by running the following commands, but none of them seem to work.

Option 1:
`gcloud compute forwarding-rules update fr-ilb --update-labels=fr-ilb-label`

Option 2:
`gcloud compute forwarding-rules update fr-ilb --update-labels=[service-label=fr-ilb-label]`

I am looking at the following documentation for guidance:
https://cloud.devsite.corp.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/update

The output of the `describe` command is as follows:

```
xxx@cloudshell:~ (ilb-test-356804)$ gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe fr-ilb --region=us-west1
IPAddress: 10.1.2.99
IPProtocol: TCP
allowGlobalAccess: true
backendService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ilb-test-356804/regions/us-west1/backendServices/be-ilb
creationTimestamp: '2022-09-06T19:54:49.330-07:00'
description: ''
fingerprint: 7wff1x8n8_g=
id: '7457513772638648598'
ipVersion: IPV4
kind: compute#forwardingRule
labelFingerprint: 42WmSpB8rSM=
loadBalancingScheme: INTERNAL
name: fr-ilb
network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ilb-test-356804/global/networks/lb-network
networkTier: PREMIUM
ports:
- '80'
- '8008'
- '8080'
- '8088'
region: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ilb-test-356804/regions/us-west1
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ilb-test-356804/regions/us-west1/forwardingRules/fr-ilb
subnetwork: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ilb-test-356804/regions/us-west1/subnetworks/lb-subnet
```

Can I please seek your help on what is it that I am missing here?

Comment: What is the output from `gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe fr-ilb`?

Comment: John, i have updated the output from the `describe` command.

Comment: Try this command `gcloud compute forwarding-rules update fr-ilb --update-labels=service-label=fr-ilb-label`. Update your question with the command results and a new describe command results.

Comment: If the issue has been solved please update. So, that it will be helpful for the community members.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out this at the official doc page
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/dns-names#a_record_format

> You can only specify a service label when you create a forwarding rule. You cannot add a service label to an existing forwarding rule. However, you can replace an existing forwarding rule with a new forwarding rule that has a service label. The replacement can use the same internal IP address as the original if you delete the original forwarding rule first.